# Select last 3 entries for each client and insert it into columns

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Need your help on the following: need to select last three comments for each client and insert it into columns. So, the input looks like this:

```
ID| Client_ID|        Comment_Date|          Comments|  
1|          1|           29-Apr-13|                 d|  
2|          1|           30-Apr-13|                dd|   
3|          1|           01-May-13|               ddd|  
4|          1|           03-May-13|              dddd|  
5|          2|           02-May-13|                 a|  
6|          2|           04-May-13|                aa|  
7|          2|           06-May-13|               aaa|  
8|          3|           03-May-13|                 b|  
9|          3|           06-May-13|                bb|  
10|         4|           01-May-13|                 c|
```

The output I need to get is as follows:

```
Client_ID|  Last comment|   (Last-1) comment|   (Last-2) comment|  
        1|          dddd|                ddd|                 dd|  
        2|           aaa|                 aa|                  a|  
        3|            bb|                  b|   
        4|             c|
```

Please, help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.client_id = x.client_id 
   AND y.id >= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.client_id
     , x.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=3;
```

Comment: This will get him the top 3 of each group, but you'd still have to convert it to a crosstab query.

Comment: Yes - except I'd handle that at the application level instead

Comment: Strawberry, thank you for the code! The first part of the puzzle is solved!  So how to convert it to the crosstab and get the final result?

Comment: As commented, I think it's better to handle issues of data display (as opposed to issues of data storage and retrieval) at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP). That said, pivot table queries have been covered within these fair walls many, many times before!

Answer (score -1):

If don't think you can get this with an SQL request. Maybe you can, but i think it's easier with PHP. For example, you can get your comments with this request :

```
SELECT * FROM Comment
WHERE Client_ID = ?
LIMIT 0,3
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

It will return to you the three last comments of an user. Then, you can do whatever you want with that !

Hope it'll help.

Comment: You can, and what's more, it's quite straightforward.